# Performance-heavy function which adds an event listener on every polygon within a very large SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, svg

I've got a large map made up of hexagons in one large SVG. I've created this function in which as the user hovers over the SVG, it adds an event listener to every hexagon which in turn performs a function that compares the distance between the mouse and each hexagon, and in turn gets those within a distance of 30px and adds CSS styling to them which makes them proportionally scale down in size in regards to the mouse position.

This works well enough but it can get pretty choppy when hovering over a lot of hexagons and or increasing the distance detection. I'm an amateur when it comes to all of this so I might not be aware of much easier and probably more optimal ways of going about this.

Here's the code:

```
function hexagonHover() {
    for (i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
        poly[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
            for (i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {

                var pos = poly[i].getBoundingClientRect();

                let _x = Math.round(pos.left + pos.width / 2);
                let _y = Math.round(pos.top + pos.height / 2);
                
                var mouseX = Math.round(event.clientX);
                var mouseY = Math.round(event.clientY);

                var a = _x - mouseX;
                var b = _y - mouseY;

                var dist = Math.round(Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b));

                if (dist <= 30) {

                    let v = mapRange(dist, 0, 30, 1.2, 0.2);

                    poly[i].style.webkitTransform = poly[i].style.transform =
                        "scale(" + v + ")";
                    poly[i].style.webkitTransform = poly[i].style.transformOrigin =
                        "center";
                    poly[i].style.webkitTransform = poly[i].style.transformBox = "fill-box";
                    poly[i].style.transition = "transform ease 1s";
                } else {
                    poly[i].style.webkitTransform = poly[i].style.transform = "scale(1.0)";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Here's a codepen which demonstrates the effect albeit on a much smaller scale](https://codepen.io/joshahayes01/pen/oNwJwZR)

Comment: 1. Don't do the calculations on each hover; do all calculations up front and assign the result to each polyline. 2. Don't transform a polyline, add an extra Polyline you position **(h)over** a polyline, so the underlying polyline do not cause any DOM reflows

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman What would be the best way to assign the distance results to each polyline? Would creating an array with all the results in the same order as the polyline array work or could I use data-attributes?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I've created a new function but I've just added an eventlistener to the doc instead of adding one to each hexagon because I still needed an event to get the current mouse position. And I'm storing the dist results in an array. Would this work? And what would be the best way to copy a polyline over the existing one in js? Cheers

Comment: There is no best way, you are the programmer and doing what you think best. By your description it sounds like you are on the right track. Basic premise is to do as many calculations as possible up front. That should get you a major improvement. If it is not enough you use JavaScript to position an **extra** polygon in a hight Z-layer on the screen.